# What happens to a ZeroMQ multipart message when send fails before the final part?

Tags: c, zeromq

I'm intending to use multi-part messages in ZeroMQ, but I need to know what happens to the initially enqueued message parts when I get a send error before the last message part is sent.

For example, lets say I have a PUSH socket and I am sending a two part message because I am collecting the header and body from different sources. What happens if the header sends fine, but there is an error sending the body? Does the header remain in the socket's outbound queue until I attempt to send another message, or does the header get dropped due to the error in the body send?

Perhaps some code will make the question more precise:

```
int header[] = {1, 2, 3};           // <- Header From Source 1
int body[]   = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};  // <- Body From Source 2

void *ctx  = zmq_ctx_new();
void *push = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_PUSH);

zmq_connect(push, "tcp://localhost:7890");

int headerSent = 0;
int bodySent   = 0;

headerSent = zmq_send(push, &header[0], sizeof(header), ZMQ_SNDMORE);
if (-1 != headerSent)
{
    bodySent = zmq_send(push, &body[0], sizeof(body), 0);
    // What if ^-- this fails?
}

// Do some other processing to prepare a new header and body here...

headerSent = zmq_send(push, &header[0], sizeof(header), ZMQ_SNDMORE);
if (-1 != headerSent)
{
    bodySent = zmq_send(push, &body[0], sizeof(body), 0);
}
```

Is it possible for me to have a message with two headers here, or does ZeroMQ discard the initial message parts that were submitted with the ZMQ_SNDMORE flag when a subsequent send fails due to (e.g.) interruption from a signal? I'm hoping that is the case because the documentation on [zmq_send](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-send) promises that all message parts will be delivered, or none of them will be delivered. However, I'm not sure how the library decides which message parts are from the same message. Does it consider two message parts to be from the same message if a send error occurs in between them?

Comment: I raised an issue for this on Github, since the docs are not clear: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/issues/4664

Answer (score 2):

[ZeroMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Multipart-Messages):

> - When you send a multipart message, the first part (and all following    parts) are only actually sent on the wire when you send
>     the final    part.
> - You will receive all parts of a message, or none at all.

What you could always do is send single part messages and assemble them and manage failure on the receiving end

Recent update: [Pieter Hintjens: The End of ZeroMQ Multipart](http://hintjens.com/blog:84)

Comment: That still doesn't tell me if an initial part is discarded on errors in subsequent parts. Can I be sure it will not hang around and become the first part of a new message?

Comment: Since `zmq_send` is asynchronous in that case, if you have an error, you most probably will get [errors](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-send) on all/subsequent calls, as the socket is in the wrong state, hence the next multipart message won't be sent either. I'd try to simulate the failure (i.e. a too large message), and if it proves too hard to materialize, postpone the concerns

Comment: You won't necessarily get errors on all subsequent calls. zmq_send can return -1 if you were interrupted during transfer due to your process receiving a signal. I wouldn't expect this to leave the socket in an invalid state. The general UNIX way to handle this type of situation is to retry the failed call. However, I don't know what state I am left in after failure, so I'm not sure how to do the retry correctly. Maybe I should read the source code...

Comment: @A.Levy As Dmitry has directed you, you might want to accept a ZeroMQ "Zero-Warrants" (nothing is guaranteed) philosophy. Using UNIX/other system-level sockets experience is **not adequate** (not usefull due to principal differences from the high-level concept down to the metal) on the grounds of ZeroMQ formal communication patterns' framework. **The best next step is to take a time and read, rethink & experiment with Pieter HINTJEN's great book and first-hand experience in "Code Connected, Volume 1"** ( available in PDF )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what will happen, however logic dictates one of 3 outcomes:

1. The 2nd frame, which failed, will have successfully processed the `0` in the multipart parameter instead of ZMQ_SNDMORE.  The first message will be dropped, and the 2nd message will start anew.
2. The 2nd frame, which failed, will ***not*** have successfully processed the `0` in the multipart parameter instead of ZMQ_SNDMORE.  The first message will still be open, your 2nd "header" will be frame 2, your 2nd "body" will be frame 3, and the message will just send with 3 frames instead of 2, erroneously
3. ZMQ will have its pants around its ankles, and be in some error state which will respond in unexpected ways.

My expectation is that the 2nd possibility is what will happen, if the call fails that it should produce zero side effects so it will be as if it never happened.  This is supported by the info on [the man page](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-send) talking about the several error types that you might encounter. In particular it looks like it should be a very rare/exceptional situation where the first part of a multipart message would be accepted by the 2nd would not.